# scroll appearance disturbs the width of html page

Tags: html, css, scroll

in my HTML page, which is `height: 100vh`, and there is some collapse accordion in it when I try to expand those accordions, the page height get extends and scroll-bar get to appear, which slightly pushes the page width which I want to avoid.

Comment: Can you post an example that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: you can add `overflow-y: scroll` to body so that the scroll bar will be always show even when not opening the accordion.

Answer (score 3):

you could use this ways:

1. List item set the overflow parameters in css

   `overflow-y:auto;
   overflow-x:hidden;`
2. use absolute parameter in display for expanding div

   `.collapsed.in > div{
       position:absolute;
   }`

Comment: Give some code demonstration with example to OP otherwise add your comment or suggestion in comment section.